# Class 1 SMPS with Y capacitor for stacking

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I am connecting Class 1 SMPS, suspects there is Y capacitor is there, I am connecting resistive load to SMPS. EMI is not a problem. Can I modify the SMPS so that I can stack two SMPSs? (The SMPS is cheap chinese make and have no datasheet)

Comment: The Y-capacitors have little influence on whether you can connect the outputs in series or not.

Comment: For my device earth leakage is more when two SMPS are connected from same outlet, not a series connection.

Comment: I interpreted “stack” as series.

Comment: Not in series, two SMPS seperately to seperate loads in same power outlets, no ways the SMPS are connected.

Answer (score 4):

> The SMPS is cheap chinese make and have no datasheet

Then it's impossible to know whether this can be done safely.

If you need specified operation, buy a device with specifications (it's a bit surprising to me that I have to spell this out).